# Had ubuntu/7 on my system reformated and ubuntu stopped working

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, uninstall, boot-repair

Well I had got a virus on the windows part of my computer. I wasn't thinking and a reformatted the hard drive... kinda screwed things up. Normally before this happened I would turn on my computer and select ether Ubuntu or 7.

From what I know Ubuntu is not on my computer.(Not that I know much still a newbie to Ubuntu as well as dual booting). When I turn on my computer I still get asked whether I want to boot into windows/Ubuntu. I would like to remove it from asking to boot into Ubuntu and get it back to just windows. After that I probably go back and re install Ubuntu.

Many thanks for any help I receive!!!!

Comment: How  did you Installed Ubuntu?

Comment: The windows installer.

Comment: When I reformatted I went to try using the uninstaller but it wasn't on the windows and I could not boot into Ubuntu. The only thing of Ubuntu that was visible to me was when I was asked which os I would like to boot into.

Comment: Please indicate your [Boot-Info URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info).

Answer (score 1):

If you '*just formatted*' your PC, then several different things *may* have occurred:

- If you formatted just the **Windows** partition, then *Ubuntu* will be unaffected.
- If you re-formatted the whole drive, it may be very difficult to restore the old partitions (to as they were).
- If you used a **Windows-based** tool to re-format the drive, you would *likely* need a **Windows-based** tool to try and **undo** this action.
- Any attempt to re-install, re-partition, de-frag, *chkdsk /f*, etc. will **very likely** prevent any attempt to recover any overwritten data (or settings).

---

( *You don't need to answer these for us, just yourself.* )

**Step 1:** What do you **need to** recover (data or settings)?

**Step 2:** What (if any) backups or copies do you have?

**Step 3:** Do you need to start some *heroic* recovery effort?

**Step 4:** What is the simplest way to simply re-install your PC?

***AND REMEMBER: Backup disks, USB storage, and Cloud storage are your friends.***

Comment: There is nothing from the Ubuntu side of my PC I wish to recover. I simple want it to stop asking me. If i would like to boot into Ubuntu. The windows side is running perfectly and is stable (has been for about 6 days so far) I would like to make it so it is only windows on my computer.